# How to read BNF syntax of C?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, programming-languages, syntax

Today I heard of [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) which is a language for languages. Also heard that it specifies the entire syntax of C in four pages. So I thought of checking it out. After reading through [this](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/bnf.html) page, I got a fair idea about how to read the syntax.

But I don't understand what the first two lines mean:

```
%token int_const char_const float_const id string enumeration_const
%%
```

Also I am reading BNF just because I am just curious. How should I proceed to understand the formal syntax by reading BNF?

[Here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf) is the BNF syntax of C.

Comment: Search for "`%token`" on the first link you gave, and you'll find an explanation that appears to answer your own question.  Is there something about that which wasn't satisfactory?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what research you've done.  Questions about the syntax of specific tools are likely off-topic here but might be appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was wondering somewhat why you do not seem interested in my
answer. I realize it contradicts your [second link to the web](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/bnf.html).  Thus I
added a note in my answer. In my informed opinion, the document posted
by Pete Jinks is too informal to serve as a reference document and
does not make much sense from a terminology point of view, since any formalism rich enough to describe
the CF syntax of a programming language will be what he calls a
variant of BNF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Backus Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) does not define special syntax for `%token`.  So that would be a special syntax custom-added by a particular person or web page or tool.  Tool support is off-topic here, but if search for "%token" on the first link you gave, you'll find a brief explanation that appears to describe what `%token` means in the context of that particular example.

In other words: if you only want to understand BNF at a conceptual level, ignore it.  That's something that's not part of BNF, but is an add-on that was added for some special purpose.  If you want to understand that the specific syntax used by some specific tool (e.g., YACC), your best source is probably the reference manual for that tool.

Answer (score 1):

### The document you are using is not BNF (Backus-Naur Form)

BNF is a language used to specify CF grammars. Like most languages
it has a reference syntax. It always possible to define another syntax
for the same language.

For example you could use another syntax for Python where all the
English keywords are replaced by German keyword, and the semi-colon is
replaced by the keyword `semi-colon`. It would work as well, but it
would not be considered standard Python. You could even make more drastic syntactic changes without really changing the way it works, including use of `begin` and `end` in place of indentation.

Similarly BNF has a reference syntax which is described in various
documents, including [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form). Their are variants, like
EBNF (extended BNF) that allow for the use of regular expressions as
the right hand-side of rules.

But basically, BNF is just a standard syntax to write context-free
(CF) grammars.

The document you refer to does contain a CF grammar. But the syntax is
not BNF (and since BNF is just a standard syntax for CF grammars, the use of the name BNF
is abusive).

**NOTE**
I realize (belatedly) that your second link (which I missed) points to a [document](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/bnf.html) where the author [Pete Jinks](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/) takes a different point of view.
It only shows that **you should always be careful with information found on the web** (including from myself), and double check it. He calls it a variant of BNF, but it is as much a variant as my caricature of Python (and I could have made it worse) is a variant of Python. Just try to use it to exchange Python programs with other people.  Or double check what he and I are saying with other reference information on the web.

### Reading a specification

You are supposed to know how to read a CF grammar.

The *real* BNF syntax may look strange sometimes, because it is a
meta-syntax (the syntax of a language for describing the syntax of other languages), and thus it requires various forcing devices, like those
needed to include in a string the symbols used as string delimiters,
for example with a backslash, or to include a "*" as symbol in a regex
that already uses the same symbol as an operator.

Another aspect is that the syntax of a programming language is usually
decomposed in two levels:

- lexical specification usually done with finite stete technology, or
  regular expressions. It specifies the spelling of terminals of the CF
  syntax, i.e. what is sometimes called tokens.
- context free syntax, which is often expressed in BNF since the
  langage Algol 60.

Terminals are usually infinite in number, which does not do well for a
finite specification of CF syntax (a formal requirement for CF grammars). Hence most of them are grouped in a
finite number of families, called in your exanple:
  - `id` for identifiers such as `foobar`
  - `int_const` for integer literals such as `23`
  - etc...

The syntax of these potentially infinite families is not usually
included in the BNF, and use of any such terminal is replaced by the
name of the family.

**It is the list of names of these families of terminals (tokens) that
is listed in the lines you worry about.**

In standard BNF, they may not be described at all, and left to a
complementary specification. Then they can be identified by the fact
they they are not the left-hand side of any rule.

Alternatively they can be associated with rules of a regular grammar
defining them, also written in BNF. But this may be confusing. One
major reason is that the separation between lexical and CF syntax
usually plays a role in the interpretation of program layout,
especially spaces, tabs and other "invisible" characters.

The most common principle (though not fully used in a language like
Python) is that invisible characters can be used arbitrarily as
separators of lexical elements, but are ignored at the CF syntactic
level. This implies that ther are not to be used in lexical elements
unless explicitly permitted by the specification of the lexical
family.

Note that all other terminals such as reserved words (`if`, `else`,
`while`, ...), operators (`+`, `==`, ...) or punctuation symbols (`;`,
`,`, ...) appear directly in the BNF as strings within double quotes.

Of course, as you can see from your own example, people never quite
respect standards. Hence **it is always wise to read the tool specific
documentation**. But it is useful to have the standard as reference to
understand what it means and what it is for.